# Backreference inside group inside lookahead

Tags: python, regex

I have `s = 'QMMQSM'`. I want to get back `['QMM']`. *Overlapping matches count*. Why doesn't this work?

`re.findall('(?=(\w(\w)\2))',s)`

If I have two characters X and Y, I need to match `XYY` like `MOO` or `BOO`. 
Bonus: How do I force X not equal to Y?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
print re.findall(r'(?=(\w(\w)\2))',s)

                ^^
```

You need to use `r` .Its raw method.That would remove `escaping`issues`.

or

```
print re.findall('(?=(\w(\w)\\2))',s)

                             ^^
```

This will allow regex to access `\2` which python would process.

```
 re.findall(r"(?=((\w)(?!\2)(\w)\3))",s)
```

You can use this to enforce `X not equal to Y`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/11

Comment: I need to match overlapping strings, so I need the lookahead

Answer (score 0):

Using `findall` returns the text that your regex matches.  Because lookaheads don't consume anything, your text matches, but the match contains no text.  It just looks ahead, sees the right stuff, and matches the empty string before the `(\w(\w)\2)`.

You can get the group out if you use `search` instead of `findall`, so you get a match object back:

```
>>> re.search(r'(?=(\w(\w)\2))',s).group(1)
'QMM'
```

(You could also use `finditer` which gives you an iterator over match objects rather than the matched text itself.)

Comment: Will this count overlapping matches?

Comment: @RenéG: Yes, if you use `finditer` to get all the matches.